# using fgetc to ignore words after space

Tags: c, string, file

I am using fgetc strings from a txt file.
Before the actual string the line can consist of many spaces.
Just after the string there should be no spaces between the words.

```
welcome //vaild
       hello  //valid
  hello friend //invalid
```

This is the approach I tried

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
  if (!file)
    return -1;
  char input;
   while ((input = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
   {
     if(input == ' ')
     {
       if (input + 1 != '\n' || input +1 != EOF)
       {
          printf("wrong\n");
       }
     } 
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The code prints "wrong" for the "hello friend" string but it also prints "error" if there are spaces before the valid string. Could someone give me a hint on how to modify my code?

Comment: What do you think `input + 1` do in your code?

Comment: I suppose "error" should be "wrong"?

Comment: `input` should be an `int` so EOF can fit in

Comment: Also, you're nog using `fgets` anywhere. Only `fgetc`. Why do you write `fgets` and tag it with that?

Comment: Read *carefully* documentation on [C language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). You might want to use [sscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [string functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte)

Comment: @kuro input+1 should read the next character

Comment: @klutt I have corrected it . typed to fast

Comment: @senpai, well it does not. It just adds 1 to the ascii value stored in `input`. You need to call `fgetc()` again to read the next character

Comment: Read *carefully* [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to rewrite your main loop into something like this:

```
char current, previous = 0;
while ((current = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if( current == '\n' ) {
        if( previous == ' ' ) {
            printf( "wrong\n" );
        }
    }
    previous = current;
}
```

---

ok, here's a different state machine that ignores leading spaces and detects spaces between the words or at the end of line:

```
char leading_spaces = TRUE;  // define this somewhere else
while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
    if( ch == '\n' ) {
        leading_spaces = TRUE;
        continue;
    }
    if( ch == ' ' ) {
        if( !leading_spaces ) {
            printf( "wrong\n" );
        }
    } else {  // non-space, not the leading spaces
        leading_spaces = FALSE;   // define this one as well
    }
}
```

Comment: the code doesn't print out wrong if the first line looks like this : "wrong string" there should be no spaces in between the words

Comment: This cannot detect EOF